# Two loops with STL iterators

Tags: c++, stl

How I can rewrite this one using STL iterators?

```
for (int i = 0; i < board.size(); i++) {
      for (int j = 0; j < board[i].size(); j++) {
        if (board[i][j] == '*') {
          if (board[i][j + 1] == '*') {
            j++;
            sum += a;
          } else {
            sum += b;
          }
        }
      }
    }
```

I have to see something like this (but maybe it is doesn't good idea?):

```
vector<string>::iterator board_elem;
vector<string>::iterator cell_itr;

for (board_elem = board.begin(); board_elem != board.end(); board_elem++) {
  for (cell_itr = board_elem.begin(); cell_itr != board_elem.end(); cell_itr++) {
    cout << board_elem[cell_itr];
  }
}
```

Comment: Is there a special reason, why you want to use iterators or are you just curious?

Comment: Your code will misbehave (read past the end) if the last element is a '*'. If you're using `std::string`s, then you'll just read the null (which is still wrong, but harmless).

Comment: @MarshallClow there's no null, accessing beyond the end of the string causes undefined behaviour

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, I dont see a reason, why you should use iterators here, but if you want:

```
for (auto bit = board.begin(); bit != board.end(); ++bit) {
    for (auto sit = bit->begin(); sit < bit->end(); ++sit) {
        if (*sit == '*') {
            if (*(++sit) == '*') {
                sum += a;
            } else {
                sum += b;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

if you can't guarantee that the last character is not a  `'*'`, then you have to replace the last if with the following instead:

```
if ((cit+1) != it->end()  && *(++cit) == '*') {
```

If you feel like hacking a bit, you could also use range based for loops (although I'd not recommend it):

```
for (auto& e : board) {
    bool isFirst=true; //next * will be the first one in a row
    for (auto& c : e) {
        if (c == '*') {         
            sum += b;
            if (!isFirst) {
                sum = sum - 2*b + a; //second in a row - subtract what we falsely added             
            }   
            isFirst=!isFirst;           
        } else {
            isFirst = true;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If board is defined as

```
std::vector<std::string> board;
```

then you can use

```
std::vector<std::string>::iterator board_elem;
std::string::iterator cell_itr;

for (board_elem = board.begin(); board_elem != board.end(); ++board_elem) 
{
    for (cell_itr = board_elem->begin(); cell_itr != board_elem->end(); ++cell_itr) 
    {
        // your code here using *cell_itr to get the character
    }
}
```

A better approach is to use C++11 and utilize the ranged based for loops:

```
for (auto& row : board)
{
    for (auto& col : row)
    {
        // your code here using *col to get the character
    }
}
```

Comment: How would you get j+1 with the range based for loop?

Comment: @MikeMB: Good Point.  I didn't notice he was checking the next element in the sequence.

Comment: You would do it like this: *((&j)+1)

Comment: @RichardHodges: Thanks, I haven't thought of that for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following way using iterator:

```
vector<string>::iterator board_elem; // board is a vector of string
string::iterator cell_itr;

for (board_elem = board.begin(); board_elem != board.end(); ++board_elem) {
  for (cell_itr = board_elem->begin(); cell_itr != board_elem->end(); ++cell_itr) {
    if (*cell_itr=='*') {
        ++cell_itr;
        if (cell_itr != board_elem->end() && *cell_itr=='*') {
            sum += a;
        } else {
            sum += b;
            --cell_itr;
        }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that board is a vector of strings, then I would use the searching facilities of `std::string`. Maybe like this:  *(untested code)*

```
for ( auto iter = board.begin(); iter != board.end(); ++iter ) {
    std::string::size_type j = 0;
    while (j < iter->size() - 1) {
        if ((j = iter->find(start, "**")) == std::string::npos)
            break;
        // found a "**" at offset 'j'
        // do something here
        j++;
    }
}
```

You can also use the C++11-style for loop instead of iterators:

```
for ( const std::string &str : board ) {
    std::string::size_type j = 0;
    while ( j < str.size() - 1 ) {
        if ((j = str.find(start, "**")) == std::string::npos)
            break;
        // found a "**" at offset 'j'
        // do something here
        j++;
    }
}
```

I realize that this is not strictly an answer to your question (How do I use iterators here), but (IMHO) this is a better solution to your problem.

Answer (score -2):

```
vector<vector<string> >::iterator board_elem = board.begin();

while (board_elem != board.end()) {
    vector<string>::iterator cell_itr = (*board_elem).begin();
    while (cell_itr != (*board_elem).end()) {
        cout << *cel_itr << '|';
        ++cel_itr;
    }
    cout << endl;
    ++board_elem;
}
```

As you can see, I made board a vector of a vector of strings.  The way you wrote it doesn't make any sense at all. The board iterator, in your example, would return a string.  In my example, each row of the board is a vector of strings. So, the board iterator returns a vector of strings, which are written out, delimited by a '|'.  Each row is separated by a newline.